# Tableau organization hierarchy reporting structure

Tags: tableau-api

​Hi,

I am working on building an organization hierarchy reporting structure. Please find the below image for reference. How to build a hierarchy by connecting parent Id to child Id in calculations?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOg7r.png

Expected Hierarchy Output: 
List all the reportees to Mid Lead
Output
Junior-1
Junior-2
Junior-3
Junior-4

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tableau - Mapping complex Hirerachy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48606979/tableau-mapping-complex-hirerachy)

Comment: Is this the same question you posted earlier?